# How to get the monitor number using X11

Tags: c++, linux, x11, xlib

I am getting information about monitors using `XRRGetMonitors`.
However, I have no information about the number of monitors.
I need monitor numbers as in the system (for example, in the GNOME settings)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ky4R6.png)

Comment: Did you read the documentation of `XRRGetMonitors`? It precisely allows you to get the number of monitors you have.

Comment: I need to get the index of each monitor

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think for this number we can take just a position of a monitor info struct in a list returned by XRRGetMonitors(..)

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <X11/extensions/Xrandr.h>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int monitor_count = 0;

    auto display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    if (display == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Failed to open display!" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    auto wnd = XDefaultRootWindow(display);

    // 0 = active, 1 = inactive, call it twice to get a full list, if there are 
    // inactive monitors
    XRRMonitorInfo *info = XRRGetMonitors(display, wnd, 0, &monitor_count);
    cout << "There are " << monitor_count << " monitor(s) in system." << endl;

    int i = 0;
    while (i < monitor_count)
    {
        cout << "Monitor " << i++ << " : " << XGetAtomName(display, info->name) << endl;
        info++;
    }
    XCloseDisplay(display); 
}
```

upd: no, it is not a correct example, because XRRGetMonitors does not show an inactive monitor in my config.